# Problems in converting to UTF-8 in Qt

Tags: qt, utf-8, qstring, persian

I try to show a persian string in Qt:

```
QMessageBox msg;

QString str = "یا حسین";
msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8(str));
msg.exec();
```

but it shows the following error :

> /home/msi/Desktop/VoMail
>   Project/Project/VoMail-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/../VoMail/mainwindow.cpp:40:
>   error: no matching function for call to 'QString::fromUtf8(QString&)'

I want to use a string variable, and not a string directly.

How can I convert a QString variable to Utf8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf8), `QString::fromUtf8()` does not accept an argument of type `QString`.  You must give it a `const char *`, so you could rewrite it like this:

```
QMessageBox msg;

QString str = QString::fromUtf8("یا حسین");
msg.setText(str);
msg.exec();
```

Comment: in Qt version 2, cannot set non-const parameter in `fromUtf8()` method. instead we can do it with `QString::fromUtf8("یا علی");` statement.

Answer (score 1):

its not good idea write like that

using this must be better

```
 QString str(tr("ya hossein");
```

and use linguist and add persian translation file to your project http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-translators.html

and if you dont want use this, you must be sure your IDE or code editor (like qtcreator) use utf8 for saving files and just use

```
 QString str("یا حسین");
```

it must be ok, i tested that so many times